# Trying to understand how to work with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I import a project into eclipse from svn and then go and run 'mvn install' from the command line and everything compiles fine. But I don't understand why the code is not compiled in Eclipse too.

From my previous experience I know that I need to go ahead in Eclipse and import "existing maven projects" to have Eclipse compile the code, I just don't understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: you might have to provide the error stack trace.

Comment: Is there an error in Eclipse? There is a view named 'Problems' in Eclipse you should check out (Window->Show View->Problems) that will list all build problems

Comment: Good question. I already imported "exiting maven projects" so now I have no problems and it compiles. The only thing is that the code appears twice -- once as a single project that is not compiled, and once again as multiple compiled projects. When I make a change to one of the sub-projects it's reflected immediately in the single un-compiled project as well.

Comment: Hmm I've seen that when I import a directory of maven projects I get both the root pom project listing all sub-projects and one project per sub-project. I ususally just close to root project and work on each project separately.

Comment: What is the issue listed in the Problems tab of Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

How have you imported the projects to Eclipse? By runnint `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to import them as 'Java project' or importing the maven projects directly with the [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin?

By default maven builds each project into a directory `target` in each project whereas Eclipse builds into `eclipse-out`. `mvn install` builds each maven project to create an archive (jar, war, ear etc) whereas Eclipse needs to build to be able to run the code in Eclipse.

Comment: I used the svn plugin to import the project to Eclipse and that's it. Then from the command line I ran 'mvn install' in the project directory inside the workspace where the main pom.xml resides.

Comment: The method you listed will only work if they have the "maven-eclipse-plugin" plugin defined in their pom file.